# Issues trying to recursively populate and print out all inductive functions of two sets

Tags: c++, function, recursion, one-to-one

I am having trouble figuring out how to make my recursive functions work properly.  The idea is that I have two sets A and B and I need to print all of the inductive functions of A to B.  This is my recursive function for doing this however the output (listed below) is not accurate and I while I can see why the issue exists I am having trouble figuring out how to solve it...

Currently I have the correct number of outputs for A = {a,b,c} and B = {1,2,3,4} which is 24, but they contain functions with repeated numbers in them which is not acceptable.  Also I lose the B[0] once I pass it and therefore lose the subset {2,1,3} for example...

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
void nextFunction(vector<string> A,
                  vector<string> B,
                  vector<string> func,
                  int left,
                  mpq_class total,
                  int index) {
    if (left == 0) {
        print(func, A);
        return;
    }

    for (int i = index; i < B.size(); ++i) {
        func.push_back(B[i]);
        nextFunction(A, B, func, left-1, total, index+1);
        func.pop_back();
    }
}

void print(vector<string> function, vector<string> A) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (A.size()); ++i) {
        cout << "(" << A[i] << "," << function[i] << ") ";
    }

    cout << endl;
}
```

Output:

> (a,1) (b,2) (c,3)
>
> (a,1) (b,2) (c,4)
>
> (a,1) (b,3) (c,3)
>
> (a,1) (b,3) (c,4)
>
> (a,1) (b,4) (c,3)
>
> (a,1) (b,4) (c,4)
>
> (a,2) (b,2) (c,3)
>
> (a,2) (b,2) (c,4)
>
> (a,2) (b,3) (c,3)
>
> (a,2) (b,3) (c,4)
>
> (a,2) (b,4) (c,3)
>
> (a,2) (b,4) (c,4)
>
> (a,3) (b,2) (c,3)
>
> (a,3) (b,2) (c,4)
>
> (a,3) (b,3) (c,3)
>
> (a,3) (b,3) (c,4)
>
> (a,3) (b,4) (c,3)
>
> (a,3) (b,4) (c,4)
>
> (a,4) (b,2) (c,3)
>
> (a,4) (b,2) (c,4)
>
> (a,4) (b,3) (c,3)
>
> (a,4) (b,3) (c,4)
>
> (a,4) (b,4) (c,3)
>
> (a,4) (b,4) (c,4)

Comment: Do you maybe mean _injective_ functions?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't really think this problem is a good candidate for recursion, your algorithm might look something like the following:

```
PrintPossibleFunctions (range_values, already_chosen, fn_def):

    if fn_def.size() == domain.size():
       print elements in order, preceded by the corresponding domain element
       return

    for value in range_values:
        if value not in already_chosen:
           already_chosen.insert(value)
           fn_def.push(value)
           PrintPossibleFunctions(range_values, already_chosen, fn_def)
           fn_def.pop()
           already_chosen.remove(value)
```